# Is there any significance between God's order to Saul in 1 Samuel 15:3 and Saul's order in Nob per 1 Samuel 22:19?

Tags: 1-samuel

I was wondering if there is any parallel between Saul's command by God (which he disobeyed):

> Now go, attack the Amalekites and totally destroy all that belongs to
> them. Do not spare them; put to death men and women, children and
> infants, cattle and sheep, camels and donkeys.’” - 1 Samuel 15:3

and Saul's order later on against the city of Nob...

> 18 Then the king said to Doeg, “You turn around and attack the
> priests.” And Doeg the Edomite turned around and attacked the priests,
> and he killed that day eighty-five men who wore the linen ephod. 19
> And he struck Nob the city of the priests with the edge of the sword,
> both men and women, children and infants; also oxen, donkeys, and
> sheep he struck with the edge of the sword. - 1 Samuel 22:18, 19.

In both cases, the order was to kill men and women, children and infants, cattle and sheep, camels and donkeys. Is this just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similarity between the two events:

- Saul was involved in both - in the 1 Sam 15 he disobeyed God by not destroying the Amalekites; in the 1 Sam 22 Saul also disobeyed God by killing priests and their families

There are significant differences between the two events as well:

- The order to destroy was given by God in 1 Sam 15 but in 1 Sam 22 the order to destroy was given by a crazed human
- In 1 Sam 22 the priests had done nothing deserving of death; in 1 Sam 15 the Amalekites had had 400 years of God's patience and deserved to be destroyed
- In 1 Sam 15 Saul is instructed to kill foreigners; in 1 Sam 22 Saul issues an order to destroy the priests of his own people!!
- The order in 1 Sam 15 was given after much consideration (by God) but in 1 Sam 22 the order to destroy was given in a mad, unreasonable rage!

The incident is one in a series of very sad incidents in the second half of 1 Samuel that document the pathetic descent of king Saul into complete insanity culminating in his suicide.